# echo value inside a variable?

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, ksh

> x=102 y=x

means when i echo $y it gives x
echo $y
x      --and not 102

and when i echo $x it give 102

lets say I dnt know what is inside y

and i want the value of x to be echoed with using y someting like this

```
a=`echo $(echo $y)`
echo $a
```

Ans 102

Comment: If you're using `bash`, then `echo ${!y}`.

Comment: this worked for me echo $(($y))

Comment: that works if x is a number because `$(( ))` is arithmetic expansion.  It will give 0 if x is some arbitrary string.

Comment: @KennyTM - that's an interesting feature.  Do you know what bash calls that feature so I can read more about it?

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: "indirection"

Comment: how to do it when x contains a string....

Comment: ok this worked for string $ eval echo \$$y

Comment: @Kimi: It would be great if you could bother to use complete sentences, and possibly use even the most cursory formatting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the shell to evaluate your command twice -- once to turn $y into x, and again to get the value of $x.  The most portable way I know to do this is with eval:

```
$ /bin/sh
$ x=100
$ y=x
$ echo $y
x
$ eval echo \$$y
100
$
```

(You need to escape the first $ in the eval line because otherwise the first evaluation will replace "$$" with the current pid)

If you're only concerned with bash, KennyTM's method is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

In ksh 93 (I don't know whether this works in ksh 88):

```
$ x=102; typeset -n y=x
$ echo $x
102
$ echo $y
102
$ echo ${!y}
x
```

Confusingly, the last two commands do the opposite of what they do in Bash (which doesn't need to flag the variable using `typeset`).